# Logout on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, logout

I am working on Codeigniter and issue is unable to logout. Below is my codes.
Controller 'Login' has a function for logout.

```
function logout(){
//session destroy
}
```

View is login_view has a link with href

```
<a href="logout">Logout</a>
```

Added routes as below

```
$route['logout'] = 'Login/logout';
```

However when clicking on the link it redirects to the link 
http://localhost:8080/po/logout (po is my directory)

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use anchor you dont have to worry about the url : <li><?php echo anchor("Checkin/logout", "Logout") ?></li>. I never use a href in codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
<a href="<?= base_url()?>logout">Logout</a>
```

Add this to `.htaccess` to remove `index.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Tried that but still same.

Comment: I have added the complete link and its working now. What I did is I have added href as "http://localhost:8080/po/index.php/Login/logout" and it worked. So my new href is 
    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/logout">Logout</a>
Does it mean my base_url is wrong ?

Comment: What is your baseurl now? If you app is in the subdir po then that should be included in your baseurl

Comment: I think your `base_url` is wrong and you have a directory `po` . So in the localhost, the relative href is not correct perfectly -> set the absolute href instead

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

add this in `.htaccess` to remove `index.php`

Comment: It was .htaccess file. Though I had added all the above and done the steps before the issue didn't fix. Finally Found that the .htaccess file in directory folder was not there it was somehow. Once added issue sorted. Thanks all of you your help.

Answer (score 2):

Change your base_url as this

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectName/';
```

make a new file and paste the below code and save it as .htaccess in your root directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will remove the index.php comming in the url

change the anchor tag as following

```
<a href="<?= base_url('controller/function') ?>">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your base_url variable is defined in the config.php.
Then try this code below.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url . 'logout'; ?>">Logout</a>
```

Comment: I have this in config 
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/po/';
As mentioned the directory is 'po'

Answer (score 0):

There is wrong configuration. Fix it

`$config['base_url']` should be

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/po/';
```

And link should be

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('logout');?>">Logout</a>
```

`site_url()` will take your configuration better than  `base_url()`. base_url only should use in asset link like CSS,JS etc.

Comment: Actually my base_url is having the 'http' while am adding the comment its been removed. I fixed with a step.
Added the checked session data in index function which will call for logout function and destroys the session.

Comment: That is also not working, only option is adding index.php on the href.
'<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/logout">Logout</a>'

Answer (score 0):

```html
Controller Function

function logout()
 {
  $this->session->sess_destroy();
  redirect('user');
 }

Menu Link
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/logout">Logout</a></li>
```